# How can I find long running transactions in WebSphere MQ Series?

Tags: transactions, jms, ibm-mq

In a [J2EE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_EE) environment, the WebSphere MQ server log shows the following:

Process(954584.5) User(mqm) Program(amqzmuc0)
AMQ7469: Transactions rolled back to release log space.
....

While increasing the logfile size/space might be a temporary solution, the definitive solution must be to identify the culprit process/queue that causes this long transaction.

Is there a solution or tool for this?

Note: WebSphere MQ is used via [JMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service) only

Answer (score 3):

You want the DISPLAY CONN TYPE(CONN) ALL command, paying attention to the UOW* attributes.  See:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=reference-display-conn-display-application-connection-information

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken. It redirects to a generic page.

Comment: @PeterMortensen updated with a current link.